android api call failed, not waiting for ('onCharacteristicRead', 42) using bleak in kivymd
I am making a kivymd app that uses bleak I send and read some characteristics everything works fine in pc but when I export the apk to android and test it on my phone I get this error : Exception during signal sending: api call failed, not waiting for ('onCharacteristicRead', 42)
I set the minimum api to 33 and I have android 13 , scanning, connecting and sending all work I can control an LED on my device.
here is the code related to the error :
    async def send_signal(self, value):
        if self.client and self.client.is_connected:
            try:
                await self.client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, bytearray([value]), response=True)
                print(f"Sent value {value}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception during signal sending: {e}")
        else:
            print("Client is not connected")

    async def read_batt(self):
        if self.client and self.client.is_connected:
            try:
                data = await self.client.read_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                self.batt_txt.text = f"{data.decode('utf-8')}"
                print(f"Received battery data: {data.decode('utf-8')}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception during signal sending: {e}")
        else:
            print("Client is not connected")
    def get_batt(self, instance):
        loop.run_until_complete(self.send_signal(3))
        loop.run_until_complete(self.read_batt())


Can you please add the Android manifest file to show the permissions and the code that shows how you're requesting these permissions at runtime? Also, have you tried adding delays in your code to see if it's a timing problem?

I use buildozer.spec file (kinda like the manifest file but for kivy) I made sure I listed all Bluetooth permissions needed : ' android.permissions =BLUETOOTH,BLUETOOTH_SCAN,BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION' I requested them at runtime and I tried manually activating them from settings, also yes I do have delays in the code to see if it is a timing problem , I even made the device constantly notify the characteristic still not able to read(everything else works scanning, connecting and writing). @YoussifSaeed
